# How can LilyPad Arduino communicate with Android devices?

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino, wifi

I would like to connect the sewable LilyPad with my Android device. I am considering making the connecting between my android device and LilyPad using Wifi or Bluetooth. Which of these two should i use to establish the best connection?
Also, how can i make the connection?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience bluetooth using a BT2 serial adapter (for instance a HC-06) is really simple. The arduino sees it as a serial peripheral (so you just have to connect RX and TX), while Android has serial classes.

The wifi connection has a much higher range and can be used to make even more complicated things, but

1. the adapter (shield) costs much more
2. it's harder to code in both arduino and android.

So if you have to use wifi, then use it. But if you just have to send some data then use the bluetooth ;)

Comment: thnx for your reply!!! so which is the easiest way to make the connection in order to pass messages from android to lilypad? i just want to light up some Leds on the TShirt using my smartphone

Comment: As I told, on android you should see the bluetooth peripheral as a serial stream (so you can write bytes to it), while the HC-06 or similar sends them to the arduino through the RX and TX buttons, so exactly the same way you send them through the console.